# How to apply a formula on column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
str_id : {VW ,VW, rate, rate},
price : {100k,200k,8 ,  7.9},
date: {2020-08-10,2020-08-11, 2020-08-10,2020-08-11}
```

I want to calculate price change this way (newprice-oldprice)/newprice for each date but I want to calculate it for separately for each str_id. For example I will calculate for rate and then I will calculate for VW. How do I do that in a short python way?

So now I will have another column which is price difference:

```
str_id date         change
VW     2020-08-10   NAN
VW     2020-08-11   -0.499
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: Where is information which value is `new` and `old` ?

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @jezrael yes. Some values are in the order of 1000 and while for other category its just 0-10

Comment: OK, please check links above and edit question.

Comment: I  have updated the answer